# Python application that runs two flask APIs in production

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn

I have a python application which (amongst other things) provides two flask APIs on different ports. Running my script directly (`python myApp.py`) runs my application as I would expect, and I have been testing it like this.

I am now attempting to get my application production ready and so want to sit my application behind something like Gunicorn and nginx. My problem is I can't work out how to do this given my application hosts two APIs on two different ports? Or should I change my application architecture entirely and have a seperate Python application for each API?

Currently I start a new process for each endpoint.

main.py:

```
ep1Thread = multiprocessing.Process(target=Endpoint1)
ep1Thread.start()

ep2Thread = multiprocessing.Process(target=Endpoint2)
ep2Thread.start()
```

Endpoint1.py:

```
app: Flask
api: Api

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

api.add_resource(Ep1V1, "/ep1/v1")
api.add_resource(WorkerProcessor, "/workerServices")
api.add_resource(SendFile, "/output/<string:fileName>", "/src/js/<string:fileName>")
app.run(host = "192.168.192.168", port = 12345)
```

Endpoint2.py:

```
app: Flask
api: Api

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

api.add_resource(Ep2V1, "/ep2/v1")
app.run(host = "10.1.10.1", port = 12346)
```

Comment: Running `python myApp.py` serves two API on two different ports?  If that's the case, probably best give a sample of how this is implemented in your code, which will help people assist.

Comment: Can you add how you'd like Nginx to handle requests. Two separate domains mapping to each Flask api e.g. api1.example.com -> port 7000 and api2.example.com -> port 8000 OR a single domain with paths mapping to different ports e.g. example.com/api1 -> port 7000 and example.com/api2 -> port 8000 ?

Comment: @pjcunningham, I would like to have a single domain, but use different ports to choose which API the request goes to. e.g. api.example.com:12345 -> API 1 and api.example.com:12346 -> API 2

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason why you want to have two endpoints on two different ports? Why not host the app on a single port and have two separate routes like this:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/endpoint_1')
def endpoint_1():
    return 1

@app.route('/endpoint_2')
def endpoint_2():
    return 2

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Comment: There is no particually good reason why I can't do this, but in some instances of my application I will want to have each API bound to a different NIC on the server. The server will sit in two different VLANs and I want to determine which API calls clients can access based on the originating network.

Answer (score 0):

Your NGINX config should have two server entries that listen on ports 12345 and 12346 for the same domain and change the ports your Flask apps are listening on, say 8000 and 9000.

```
server {
        listen 12345;

        server_name api.example.com;

        location / {
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_redirect off;
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
        }

}


server {
        listen 12346;

        server_name api.example.com;

        location / {
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_redirect off;
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9000;
        }

}
```